# How to get access to 64 bit folder (System32) from 32 bit Delphi application using batch file?

Tags: delphi, batch-file

I'm trying to execute this test batch file from 32 bit application made in delphi 7. I'm using simple **ShellExecute('install.cmd',SW_HIDE)** function. The problem is that due to 32 bit host application first line is ignored. I know why windows does that but my question is how to disable that default behaviour. I tried replacing "System32" with "SysNative" but it was interpreted by xcopy as regular folder.

**Install.cmd**

```
  xcopy "SomeLibrary_64bit.dll" "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\" /Y 
  xcopy "SomeLibrary_32bit.dll" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\" /Y
```

Comment: `%windir%\sysnative` should work in a WOW64 environment. Otherwise, you can either 1) use `CreateProcess()` to launch the 64-bit version of `cmd.exe` directly, or 2) use [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx) and [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365745.aspx). Of course, the real question is, why is your software launching a `.bat` script instead of just using the `CopyFile()` function?

Comment: Seconded. Don't use a batch file for this. Beyond that, it's a mistake to modify the system directory. Don't do that.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 
I've created simple installer for AviSynth+ MT and I want to execute that installation script directly from my 32 bit app.
Regarding %windir%\sysnative. It does exactly the same as %systemroot%\Sysnative. Sysnative only works from delphi but it does not work with xcopy. I will try launching this script via 64 bit cmd.exe.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: it is not xcopy's job to interpret `SysNative`. That is handled by WOW64's [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) when *any* 32-bit app tries to access a file in the `SysNative` folder.  It is silently redirected to the real `System32` folder

Answer (score -1):

Ok. It turns out that solution to my problem is to execute script via specific 64 bit cmd.exe. For example

```
RunCMD(WinDir+'\SysNative\cmd.exe /c "'+programdir+'\Tools\AviSynth\Install.cmd"',SW_HIDE);
```